# How do I count and replace elements in an sql column

Tags: sql

I have a table with a column that contains numbers 1 - 5, it looks something like the following

```
Column
1
2
4
3
2
1
5
2
```

How do I count the number of times each number shows up so that my final table looks like this:

```
Number | Count
one    | 2
two    | 3
three  | 1
four   | 1
five   | 1
```

Comment: Are you having trouble with counting or showing 1 as one and so on?

Comment: replacing 1 with one, 2 with two, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
case 
when number = 1 then 'one'
when number = 2 then 'two'
when number = 3 then 'three'
when number = 4 then 'four'
when number = 5 then 'five'
end number,
count
from
(select number,count(*) count
 from yourtable
 group by number) s
```

In this case you have only 5 values so `case` is feasible to do the replacement. However, good practice would be to use a table with the number to name mapping and then join it to your counting query. So, assuming you have table `tblMap` with 2 columns - `number` and `name`, you would do;

```
select name, count(*)
from
yourtable t
inner join tblMap m on t.number = m.number
group by t.number, name --group by number so that results are ordered by number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      CASE
            WHEN columnx = 1 THEN 'one'
            WHEN columnx = 2 THEN 'two'
            WHEN columnx = 3 THEN 'three'
            WHEN columnx = 4 THEN 'four'
            WHEN columnx = 5 THEN 'five'
            ELSE 'unexpected' END as Number
    , COUNT(*) as count_of
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY
      CASE
            WHEN columnx = 1 THEN 'one'
            WHEN columnx = 2 THEN 'two'
            WHEN columnx = 3 THEN 'three'
            WHEN columnx = 4 THEN 'four'
            WHEN columnx = 5 THEN 'five'
            ELSE 'unexpected' END
```

Answer (score 0):

Which database you need this, if oracle then you can use below query provided your number are between the range of 1 and 5373484

```
-- works only for values between 1 and 5373484 (i.e julian date)
select to_char(to_date(num_column,'j'),'jsp'),cnt 
from 
( select num_column,count(1) cnt
  From TableA 
  group by num_column
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
case
when [Column] = '1' then 'One'
when [Column] = '2' then 'Two'
when [Column] = '3' then 'Three'
when [Column] = '4' then 'Four'
when [Column] = '5' then 'Five'
end [Number]
, COUNT (*) as [Count] from Table_Name 
group by [Column]
```